# How can I fix TFS source control explorer - it is taking too long to expand folders?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio and TFS.  TFS source control explorer takes up to 30 seconds to expand a folder in the "folders" pane.  It does not seem to do this for other users.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Where is your local mapped drive? On a network share?

Comment: Local mapped drive is on a local hard drive (My d: to be precise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to the use of a local workspace.  TFS cannot handle a codebase of reasonable size.  Change to a server workspace to fix this issue.

Comment: What are you defining as "reasonable size"?  Source control explorer should make the same calls to the server to query its data whether you're on local workspaces or server workspaces.  I would be curious to hear more.

Comment: "Reasonable size" in this case is around 100 000 separate files spread over twenty or so different solutions.